# Configure location of ~/.config/nixpkgs/config.nix

Tags: nix, nixpkgs

Is there some envvar or similar that I can use to configure the location of ~/.config/nixpkgs/config.nix ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the default Nixpkgs config file location can be set with [`NIXPKGS_CONFIG`](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/top-level/impure.nix#L30).

This will not affect invocations of Nixpkgs where the `config` parameter is set, such as

```
import <nixpkgs> { config = ...; }
```

or invocations of Nixpkgs by NixOS.

Comment: There are also (at least) 2 open issues discussing `NIXPKS_CONFIG`'s currently undocumented status: [Nixpkgs#28085](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/28085), [Nix#829](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/issues/829). (It is also [set by default on NixOS](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/dd050270c78a0e214ed7cb9e25bae43b45406473/nixos/modules/programs/environment.nix#L20).)